# MySQL returning the MIN id instead of the MAX id?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a table with an A.I column called 'id'. This column is UNSIGNED and has 6 entries. So id: 6 is the MAX value in the column. Using PHP to call forth the max id in the table, it always prints out the least value.
This is what i'm doing:

```
$MAX_ID = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM table");
                    echo "Hello" + $MAX_ID;
```

I've tried all the ways of doing this, like ORDER BY and id=("SELECT FROM MAX(id)"), but 1 is still being returned. I am using PHPMyAdmin, and when I do the SQL query there, the right value is being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you're getting is just a `MySQLi` result object (`$MAX_ID`).

Execute the query → Fetch the rows.

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM Entertainment"); // execute
$max_id = $query->fetch_array(); // fetch
echo $max_id[0];
```

Additional Note: Use `.` for concatenation, not `+`:

```
echo 'max: ' . $max_id[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [mysqli documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php). The value being returned is a result object, not the direct result data from the query: You'll need to use mysqli's accessor methods to extract actual result rows.